# Server 2012 R2 - Features on Demand - role not actually being removed

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, powershell, local-area-network, thin-provisioning

This is for learning purposes:

I'm running a Server r2 machine and I'm trying to remove feature WINS. I run uninstall-windowsfeature WINS -restart -remove, I then restart, and then run get-windowsfeature | where installstate -eq removed and I see that the WINS binaries are removed from the role store.

I then run install-windowsfeature WINS locally and the role is then installed.. So why did this happen? I thought the binaries were removed--apparantly not. Any ideas on why this is? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Install-WindowsFeature` will download data from Windows Update if the required data is not available locally. For more detail, type `Get-Help Install-WindowsFeature -Full` and then read up on the `-Source` parameter.

Comment: Is there a way to disallow the cmdlet from downloading from windows update if no files exist locally and on remote share?

Comment: @user1330287 Yes, by not using that cmdlet, or by disconnecting the computer from the internet. Or by using a hosts file to redirect Windows Update to 127.0.0.1.  ;)